# Why do if statements and recursive act this way?

Tags: python

I'm having an issue here, I'm learning python because I've always wanted to exploit and with minimal research it was easy to conclude that Python is the easiest to interpret and use.

```
import sys
    def run_program():
       print("[*] Palidrome Checker")
       word = raw_input("Enter your word: ")
       word = word.lower()
       def Palindrome(word, i):
           if(i >= 1):
                if(word[0] == word[i]):
                    i -= 2
                    Palindrome(word[1:], i)
                else:
                    return False
                    sys.exit(0)
           elif(len(word) == 1):
                print("Please enter a word, not a character")
                run_program()
           return True

       print(Palindrome(word, len(word)-1))

run_program()
```

My question here is, why does it keep returning true for words that only have the first and last letters the same, why is my if statement not returning false.

For the word 'test'
I've printed the outputs and and it compares the e to s, and but yet it isn't returning false, though the output of the first nested if statement is false. Shouldn't the else statement catch it?

Also, lets say I were to add another argument to My Palindrome function so it would look like:

def Palindrome(word, i, a)

I can't assign a to 0, but lets say I wanted to have a variable non global variable that started at zero, how could I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not a solution, but you can easily check if something is a palindrome with `x = len(word) // 2; isPalin = word[0:x] == word[-1:x:-1]`

Comment: @Felk - or just `word == word[::-1]`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I don't know why I felt the urge to only test half the word. Thanks, I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement **is** returning false, but you aren't doing anything with the result. You should `return Palindrome(word[1:], i)` instead of doing nothing with the result.

Note that your `sys.exit(0)` has no effect because it is after `return False`.

Your question about adding another parameter doesn't make much sense because you haven't explained what you want to do with it, nor what scope you want the variable to have (non-global is too vague given that you have a nested function). Note that `Palindrome()` has access to `run_program()`'s local variables.

Here's a cleaner version of your code:

```
import sys

def run_program():
    print('[*] Palidrome Checker') # move this into the loop if you want it to print before asking for input again after invalid input
    word = ''
    while True:
        word = raw_input('Enter your word: ')
        word = word.lower()

        if len(word) > 1: # quit the loop if we have a word
            break
        print('Please enter a word, not a character')

    def Palindrome(word):
        if len(word) < 2:
            return True
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            return Palindrome(word[1:-1])
        return False

    print(Palindrome(word))

run_program()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is very easy to understand I wasn't aware of the word[1:-1], where you can put -1, that would've been so useful. Guess I got to scrap this pdf I've been using. But also, I don't understand the difference, returning it or not, doesn't it do the same thing, just start the function again?

Comment: @user5618827 When you call recursively, it puts another call to the function on the stack, it doesn't just jump back to the top and start again. So when the new call is finished, it goes back to where it was before (in the first call).

Answer (score -2):

well the simplest palindrome checker would be like:

```
>>> n = 'level'
>>> True if n == n[::-1] else False # this ternary, you could do it like 'right' if n == n[::-1] else 'wrong'
True
# the simplest should be n == n[::-1]
```

Comment: Did you note that your expression is simply `n == n[::-1]`? Writing`True if X else False` instead of just `X` is quite redundant.